# Flutter animated text as counter, double not accepted

Tags: flutter

Based on this repo: https://gist.github.com/bluemix/4c932e8c4a1cd6f497a4353d9e536f57

Class:

```
    class AnimatedCount extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  const AnimatedCount({
    Key? key,
    required this.count,
    Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    Curve curve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  }) : super(duration: duration, curve: curve, key: key);

  final num count;

  @override
  ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgetState<ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget> createState() {
    return _AnimatedCountState();
  }
}

class _AnimatedCountState extends AnimatedWidgetBaseState<AnimatedCount> {
  IntTween _intCount = IntTween(begin: 0, end: 1);
  Tween<double> _doubleCount = Tween<double>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.count is int
        ? Text(_intCount.evaluate(animation).toString())
        : Text(_doubleCount.evaluate(animation).toStringAsFixed(2));
  }

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor<dynamic> visitor) {
    if (widget.count is int) {
      _intCount = visitor(
        _intCount,
        widget.count,
        (dynamic value) => IntTween(begin: value),
      ) as IntTween;
    } else {
      _doubleCount = visitor(
        _doubleCount,
        widget.count,
        (dynamic value) => Tween<double>(begin: value),
      ) as Tween<double>;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to pass data:

```
AnimatedCount(count: getKcal()), //as Text Widget
```

getKcal function is easy (as for testing purposes):

```
  double getKcal() {
    return 10;
  }
```

However I receive an exception here (on the Class AnimatedCount):

```
_doubleCount = visitor(
```

> Exception has occurred.
> _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast)

No problems when I use integers. The Class does not accept doubles and I'm not finding why...

Comment: Just updated code and repo origin (sry I taked a similar one before). Now code is fully compatible with latest Flutter/Dart. Doubles limit persists.

Comment: have you tried `return 10.0;`?

Comment: Yes I have, I also tried 10 but I needed to swith to int function (10 is not accepted as double, even if it has no decimals)

Comment: I made it work after setting `begin` and `end` properties for `_doubleCount` like `Tween<double> _doubleCount = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0);` in your `_AnimatedCountState`